# how can i change the keyboard at runtime in iphone

Tags: iphone, keyboard

how can i change the keyboard at runtime in iphone?

i have a Bar segmented control in which i have two options like "name" and "Phone no".
And i have i textbox. I want when user selects "name" and type in textbox then a default

keyboard should display but when user selects "phone no" and type in textbox then a "number pad" keyboard should display.

Plz help me.

Regards
Mike

Answer (score 3):

This is defined in the UITextInputTraits Protocol Reference. 
You can use

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

to change the keyboard type of a field.